# Getting empty string from .get() in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing a program where I need input from user from a child window in tkinter. And whenever I use `.get()` for the same it prints empty string. I read many solutions online, but I can't find solution to the problem.

Here's some sample code similar to the main one:

```
from tkinter import *

t=Tk()
def getvals():
    print(st.get())
t.geometry("250x200")
st=StringVar()

def new():
    t1=Tk()
    t1.geometry("250x200")
    Entry(t1,textvariable=st).pack()
    Button(t1,text="Enter",command=getvals).pack()
    t1.mainloop()

Button(t,text="Open new window",command=new).pack()
t.mainloop()
```

I'm running python version 3.9.0.

Comment: You shouldn't have more than one tkinter `Tk` instance running at the same time. If you want a new window to open, you should use an instance of `Toplevel` instead. Should also only have one `mainloop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment above, You shouldn't have more than one tkinter `Tk` instance running at the same time. If you want a new window to open, you should use an instance of `Toplevel` instead. Should also only have one `mainloop`.

See below for how to do this.

```
from tkinter import *
t=Tk()
def getvals():
    print(st.get())
t.geometry("250x200")
st=StringVar()

def new():
    t1=Toplevel()
    t1.geometry("250x200")
    Entry(t1,textvariable=st).pack()
    Button(t1,text="Enter",command=getvals).pack()

Button(t,text="Open new window",command=new).pack()
t.mainloop()
```

Comment: Oh thanks buddy, working now. I really didn't knew about not opening more than 1 `Tk()` instance would cause this.

Comment: The StringVar is "bound" to a specific instance of Tk so creating a new one means that any existing vars aren't visible to the new instance.